# In Cassandra, how to select rows based on a column and also update that column later

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql, composite-primary-key, denormalization

I am new to cassandra database design. My app is an orchestrator service that stores requests come from other apps (into 'inbound' table). After that, there will be a cron job that picks up rows in table and process them.

```
-inbound
    request_id     uuid
    payload        varchar    
    status_code    text        will be one of those values {RECEIVED, IN_PROCESS, FINISHED, FAILED}
    tryNumber      int         start with 0 and be increased for every try
    update_date    timestamp
    create_date    timestamp
```

Here are the queries that will be applied to this table:

```
1. insert request into this table, status=RECEIVED, create_date = update_date = current timestamp
2. pickup the first 100 (or ALL) requests with status = RECEIVED or FAILED to process.
3. for each pick-up request, update status to PROCESS and increase tryNumber and  update_date = current time
4. after processing, for each pick-up request, update status to FINISHED or FAILED, and also update_date = current time
```

I have tried to make status_code (partition key) and request_id(cluster key) to make it able to do 2nd requirement, but then it is impossible to do 3rd and 4th requirements.

I also hear that denormalize can help but i dont know how to to that.

Could you please help me on this design using cassandra database.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to build this model as a time series with a time component "bucket" to keep the partitions from growing too large.  To do that, we'll need one more column: `month_bucket`.

The "bucket" column is dependent on two things:

1. **Your business logic**.  Do you typically query for data within a certain month?  Or week?  Or does the job process it fast enough that you really only need to worry about the current day?
2. **Number of rows written over time**.  Cassandra has a cells/per-partition limit of 2 billion, size of 2GB, and the partition will become unusable long before those hard limits.  I recommend keeping no more than 20k-50k rows in a partition, and less than 10MB.

The point, is to take this example with "a grain of salt."  A different time bucket may make more sense for you (week, day, etc.).  I've built models using a bucket based on hour before, because of the expected write throughput.

So `month_bucket` will be the partition key, and we'll cluster by `create_date` in ASCending order.  That way, all the most-recently created rows will be at the "bottom" of the partition, and you'll have an easier time with queries like "get the oldest 100 w/ a certain status" (which will read from the "top" of the partition).

To query by `status_code`, you'll need a secondary index on it.  Yes, I'm sure you've read "secondary indexes are bad."  And that's true.  But, in certain cases with (what I call) "middle of the road" cardinality, they are ok.  They are particularly useful with a finite amount of options (processed, received, etc.) on a column which can change (can't change the values of primary key components).  But with the queries you describe, you'll be using a secondary index *with* the partition keys, which will limit their "badness" significantly.

In short, I'd build the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE inbound (
  request_id     uuid,
  payload        text,
  status_code    text,
  tryNumber      int,
  update_date    timestamp,
  create_date    timestamp,
  month_bucket   int,
  PRIMARY KEY (month_bucket,create_date,request_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (create_date ASC, request_id ASC);

CREATE INDEX ON inbound (status_code);
```

With this PRIMARY KEY definition, all rows will be stored by month (ex: 202110), ordered by `create_date`, and with `request_id` to help ensure uniqueness.

My only concerns here, are around the use of `tryNumber`:

1. Cassandra doesn't overwrite.  It stores obsoleted values for up to 10 days.  Too many updates, and there will be a loooooong list of obsoleted values that Cassandra has to sort through, not to mention read from multiple files on-disk.  But if the idea here is that it typically only gets updated once or twice, it'll be ok.
2. Cassandra doesn't provide ACID transactions, which makes multi-threaded operations all doing read-write-read-write a bit of an anti-pattern.  There's no way to "lock" a value to prevent it from being updated by another process (race condition).  Ex: the job reads a `tryNumber` of 0 and attempts to set it to 1, but another process sets it to 1 before that happens.  Just something to be aware of.

With this model, queries like this should work just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM inbound
WHERE month_bucket=202110 AND status_code='RECEIVED'
LIMIT 100;
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM inbound
WHERE month_bucket=202110 AND status_code IN ('RECEIVED','FAILED')
LIMIT 100;
```

Again, with the rows in ascending order by `create_date`, this should give you the oldest 100 with a particular status.  Cassandra does't have an `OR` keyword, because that incurs "random" reads, and Cassandra was built for "sequential" reads.  Using `IN` is a way around that, but use of `IN` comes with the same precautions that secondary indexes have (it's not too bad if you're using it while filtering on a partition key).

Comment: Thanks Aaron. To be more detail: The cron job will run every hour to pick up the rows which has status in (RECEIVED, FAILED) and tryNumber<8.  That means for every rows , we can do a retry to 8 times maximum.